# How to show following function is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be continously differentiable such that $ || f(x)- f(y)|| \geq  ||x-y|| \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n $. How to show $f(\mathbb{R}^n )$ is open subset of $ \mathbb{R}^n $?
My attempt : I have shown f is one one as taking $ f(x)= f(y) \implies $ $ || f(x)- f(y)|| = 0 \implies ||x-y|| =0 \quad $  hence $x=y$. Now by theorem Invariance of Domain (injective continuous map from  $\mathbb{R}^n  $ to $\mathbb{R}^n $  is open ) $f$ must be open map. Is there any other easy way to showthis using given conditions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inverse function theorem because for every $x$, $d f(x)$ will be invertible, hence $f$ is a local diffeomorphism between a neighbourhood of $x$ and a neighbourhood of $f(x)$. To show that $d f(x)$  is invertible, take $y = x+t h$ with $t> 0$, then
\begin{equation}
\|d f(x)(h)\| = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \|\frac{1}{t}(f(x) -f(x + t h))\|\ge \|h\|
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already shown that the map is injective we can define the inverse $f^{-1}:f(\mathbb R ^n)\to \mathbb R^n$.
Now we will show that $f$ is closed.
Let $f(x_n)\to y$. Hence $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^n$. Now from the given inequality we can conclude that $(x_n)$ is also Cauchy. Hence if $x_n\to z$ then by continuity of $f$ we can conclude that $f(z)=y$. Hence $y\in f(\mathbb R^n)$.
From this we can conclude that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, since inverse images of closed sets are closed. Hence inverse images of open sets under $f^{-1}$ should be open.
Hence $(f^{-1})^{-1}(\mathbb R^n)=f(\mathbb R^n)$ is open.

Comment: I have a doubt. I seems to me that the inverse images of open sets under $f^{-1}$ are open in $f({\mathbb R}^n)$, but are they open in ${\mathbb R}^n$?

Comment: I think you are right. But the proof for $f$ being closed is correct, which implies that $f(\mathbb R^n)$ has to be both open and closed and hence it has to be $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I think you are right. I am looking for 'continuous dilations of Rn' in search engines but I still cannot find a reference.

Comment: I still need some basic way to prove that it is open map.

Comment: @CHOUDHARYbhimsen My way is very basic. I think it is the most basic way.

Comment: I mean can we solve for undergraduate lavel?